# Trigger a php file on every post or page if a condition is met

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I was wondering if we can trigger a PHP file on every WordPress post or page if a certain condition is met. Let me detail what I want.

1. Can we write a simple PHP script that will be automatically loaded on every WP post and page. Once loaded, the script should scan the HTML and if it finds a specific DIV tag with the ID `myID` it should trigger another PHP file (let's say `script.php`).
2. Once the target PHP file has been triggered or executed, the target PHP file (`script.php`) should be able to automatically fetch the URL of the post or page that triggered the file and store it in a variable.

Any ideas??

Comment: A starting point for this may be `the_content` filter for finding the id https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content and of the following functions for executing second script: `wp_remote_post` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post or `wp_remote_get` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

Comment: How the element with `myID` is being inserted? Using shortcode or HTML in post editor? The best way to call a script is using AJAX.