# How to include a php file in every post and page

Tags: php, include

How to automatically include a php file in all posts and pages. The php file I want to add has a script which will automatically fetches a temporary video link every time the file is executed.

Comment: Is this a repost of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200518/trigger-a-php-file-on-every-post-or-page-if-a-condition-is-met ?

Comment: Please stay away from reposting the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Place your file in the same directory as the template. On the `single.php` and `page.php` files you'll want to include:

`<?php include('your_file.php'); ?>`